# AJAX in WordPress only returns 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to utilize WordPress's admin-ajax feature in order to build a dynamic admin panel option-set for a plugin. Essentially, once an option is selected from a dropdown (select/option menu), PHP functions will sort through and display more dropdown menus  that fall under the dropdown above it. I began with a simple return that I was hoping to utilize later down the line, but I can't seem to get the text to print out without running into `unidentified` issues.

The AJAX I set up puts out a 200 status but the response never builds, and I'm left with `0` as my result. Here's the code:

**JS/jQuery *built into PHP function `ajax-action()`***

```
$ = jQuery;
$('#platform').change(function(e) {
  var data = {
    action: 'action_cb',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $('#user_id').val(response);
    }
  };
  $.ajax(ajaxurl, data, function(data) {
    $('#user_id').val(data);
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

***PHP functions and add-actions***

```
add_action('wp_ajax_action_cb','action_cb');
add_action('admin_footer','ajax_action');
function action_cb() { $platform = 'test'; echo json_encode($platform); wp_die(); };
```

My question is: how can I fix this and prevent it from continuing to happen? I'd like to return the actual results and not `0`.

Comment: I don't think this is whats causing the problem, but there is a typo in your action_cb function. It should be wp_die() not p_die(). I will take a look into this asap.

Comment: Try, placing a `$.support.cors = true;` before your `$.ajax` statement as this may be due to CORS issue

Comment: @lassemt Yeah, I had originally tried die() but edited it on my machine after posting this and forgot the w modifying it here. Updated the post to reflect that change

Comment: @DavidR No cigar on that one. I might have to go the old fashioned route and use a ton of .show() and .hide().

Answer (score 1):

As per the wordpress documentation:

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins (Reference "Error Return Values")

A 0 is returned when the Wordpress action does not match a WordPress hook defined with add_action('wp_ajax_(action)',....)

Things to check:

1. Where are you defining your add_action('wp_ajax_action_cb','action_cb');?
   Specifically, what portion of your plugin code?
2. Are you logged into wordpress? You mentioned the admin area, so I'm assuming so, but if you are not, you must use add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}', ....)

Additionally, you didn't share the function this is tied to:
add_action('admin_footer','ajax_action');

And lastly, why are you using "json" as the data type? If you are trying to echo straight HTML, change data type to 'html'. Then you can echo directly on to page (or as a value as you are doing). Currently, you are trying to echo a JSON object as a value in the form...

So your code would look like so:

function action_cb() { $platform = 'test'; echo $platform; p_die(); };

...and your AJAX could be:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
jQuery.ajax({
url: ajaxurl,
type: 'post',
data: {'action' : 'action_cb'},
success: function (data) {
    if (data != '0' && data != '-1') {
        {YOUR SUCCESS CODE}
    } else {
        {ANY ERROR HANDLING}
    }
},
dataType: 'html'
});
</script>
```

Try This:

```
<script>
$ = jQuery;
$('#platform').change(function(e) {
var data = {
data: {'action' : 'action_cb'},
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
console.log(errorThrown);
},
success: function(response) {
$('#user_id').val(response);
}
};
$.ajax(ajaxurl, data, function(data) {
$('#user_id').val(data);
});
e.preventDefault();
});    
</script>
```

Comment: The function ajax_action() is the Javascript/jQuery. Due to the formatting restraints of StackOverflow and my lack of patience, I separated the two. Also, the $platform is a json file but for the sake of my own sanity I have a single word in its place for now.

Comment: But the reason you're getting a 0 is because it doesn't appear that you're passing the "action" POST variable to WP, thus it thinks your action hook isn't defined. Notice how I'm passing {"action" : 'action_cb'} as the data of the AJAX call. And if you need to use JSON, just change the dataType I used to 'json', and you'll get JSON in return.

Comment: How is it different from passing the action as an earlier variable? If the action gets defined in var data, wouldn't it read the same?

Comment: I'm not an expert on all the different ways of formatting your AJAX calls, but I'm doing the same thing in WP, and I can tell you the above code I posted will work 100%. I don't believe you can pass action: {} as a AJAX option in your data var, that's not an accepted Ajax option. You put the data you want to post to the server in the "data" portion of the Ajax options.

Comment: I gave it a try and no amount of tweaking made it work. I'm checking the AJAX status requests and no response is ever created.

Comment: In what file are you defining add_action('wp_ajax_action_cb','action_cb'); ? The only explanation if you're sure you're logged in, is the place you're defining the wp_ajax_{action} is wrong so wordpress isn't finding it. And did you also try my updated "Try This" code?

Comment: I can't comment on your above statement that you'll just have to go with a bunch of show() hide() since I don't have enough reputation points, but I'm literally doing the exact thing you're trying to do, and it works just fine. Other things to check: Is error reporting throwing it off? If you have errors that get generated in your PHP script during the AJAX call, you can have problems with your return data as well.

Comment: Yes, I tried the updated code. It still outputs 0 (as the error response). I've logged out and logged back in, and even tried on incognito. The wp_ajax_action_cb is placed right before the script, yet the script is added to the footer anyway.

Comment: What file the add_action('wp_ajax_action_cb', 'action_cb') is placed makes a big difference. If you're placing it in some page, for example, it won't be found by WP during the AJAX load (the AJAX calls don't load all of WP). You need to place the add_action(AJAX ACTION) in the plugin you're creating so it gets loaded during plugin initialization. Could you explain exactly what file you're putting all this in?? I'm telling you, you're getting 0's because WP can't find your action hook into wp_ajax...

Comment: It's right inside the core files for this plugin. Since I'm building the plugin, I've tried including AJAX both in the initializer and in this file (at different times, but neither have worked). The file where the dropdown menus display is called by an add_submenu_page function.

Comment: Not much more I can add without seeing your files. I'm currently building AJAX functions in my plugin as I'm answering your question, and I can tell you that if you're using the code I posted above, and still not getting a response, it's because 1) The place you're defining the add_action('wp_ajax_{action}', ....) is wrong (i.e., too late to get logged by wordpress 2) there are errors in your PHP script that are causing the function to return 0 because it failed to complete

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_action_cb', 'action_cb');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Comment: That action is for front-end and non-logged users. I'm keeping the entire operation in the admin panel. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

just make small change in your `AJAX`. I am assuming you're logged in as admin.
replace `action` in data object with `data:"action=action_cb",`

```
 var data = {

            data:"action=action_cb",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#user_id').val(response);
            }
        };
        $.ajax(ajaxurl,data,function(data){
            $('#user_id').val(data);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent WP adding zero into response i always using **die();** insted of **wp_die();**

and registering function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_action_cb', 'action_cb_init' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_action_cb', 'action_cb_init' );

function action_cb_init() {

}
```

When calling to function with AJAX use **action: 'action_cb'**

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I have already explained standard way of using ajax in wp.

[Wordpress: Passing data to a page using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566818/wordpress-passing-data-to-a-page-using-ajax/37570025#37570025)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have been recreating your code now in my own project and noticed that the javascript you shared returned the ajax-object and not the results. So what I come up with is a bit rewriting, but is worked fine when I tried it.

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j('#platform').change(function(e) {

    $j.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'action_cb',
        }           
    }).done(function( data ) {
        // When ajax-request is done.
        if(data) {
            $j('#user_id').val(data);
        } else {
            // If 0 
        }
    }).fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // If ajax failed
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

I hope the comments explain good enough how it is working. Note how I'm using **$j** instead of just $ for the jQuery.noConflict mode.

Answer (score 0):

For those by the "Load More" problem.

Normally `"0"` is used instead of `false`.

I found such a solution.

So that `0` does not come. Try this code with `false`.

PHP

```
ob_start(); // start the buffer to capture the output of the template
get_template_part('contents/content_general');
$getPosts[] = ob_get_contents(); // pass the output to variable
ob_end_clean(); // clear the buffer
if( $read == $articles->found_posts )
$getPosts[] = false;
```

JS

```
if( posts[i] == false )
$(".load_more_button").fadeOut();
```